# iOS array count returning error

Tags: ios, arrays, xml-parsing, count, tableview

I am trying to count my array to set as the number of rows in my table and then multiply it by 2 because I have an invisible cell in between each cell to make the cells look separated. Every time I try to build, I get this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]'

This is the code I am using:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  return [xmlParser.calls count] * 2; 
}
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
  static NSString *CELL_ID2 = @"SOME_STUPID_ID2";
  JointCAD *currentCall = [[xmlParser calls] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"texture3.png"]];

  [self.tableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"texture3.png"]]];

  if (indexPath.row % 2 == 1) {
    UITableViewCell * cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CELL_ID2];

    if (cell2 == nil) {
      cell2 = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                       reuseIdentifier:CELL_ID2];
      [cell2.contentView setAlpha:0];
      [cell2 setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
      [cell2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }
    return cell2;
  }

  TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }

  cell.callTypeLabel.text = currentCall.currentCallType;
  cell.locationLabel.text = currentCall.location;
  cell.unitsLabel.text = currentCall.units;
  cell.stationLabel.text = [@"Station: " stringByAppendingString:currentCall.station];
  cell.contentView.layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
  cell.contentView.layer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.contentView.frame.size.width, cell.contentView.frame.size.height);
  cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
  cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

  if ([currentCall.county isEqualToString:@"W"]) {  
    cell.countyImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"];
  } else {
    cell.countyImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"green.png"];
  }

  if ([currentCall.callType isEqualToString:@"F"]) {  
    cell.callTypeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"];
  } else {
    cell.callTypeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow.png"];
  }
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: Run your app in the debugger. You will see a stack trace showing you exactly which line of code is causing the problem. The code you posted is not the cause of the crash. The problem is going to be some line that tries to access an elements from the array.

Comment: But then how do you access your cell's values in the `-
tableView:
cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method?? 

It's a blind guess, but I think you are accessing the same `xmlParser.calls ` array to access all the cells.. `xmlParser.calls * 2`

Comment: provide your - tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath: code

Comment: I posted the additional code.

Comment: Should I be accessing the array differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Made a closer look. Just add the `/2`:

```
JointCAD *currentCall = [[xmlParser calls] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row / 2];
```

And it's going to work.
Just noticed the same answer below from `richard`.

---

As mayuur noticed:

in `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`:

```
// n = [xmlParser.calls count]
// Ok, we have n*2 items (but calls has only n!):
return [xmlParser.calls count] * 2;
// calls has n items in it, but you return n*2 items
```

And then in `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`:

```
// n = [xmlParser.calls count]
// give me object from calls at index (which will be in range [0; n*2 - 1], 
// which could be beyond [0; n-1] which you originally have)
JointCAD *currentCall = [[xmlParser calls] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

So you should remove multiply by 2 or suggest something by your own, you'll always going to get this error unless xmlParser.calls is an empty array.

Comment: You'we probably did something wrong, adding /2 should not cause this unless you'we changet something else

Comment: Awesome. Works perfectly. *I made a stupid mistake and fixed it :P

Answer (score 0):

The error occured as you're doing something like `cell.textLabel.text = [array  objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` it over bounds it limits. However of your requirement to left invisible (blank) cells in between, you can set some `if...else` conditions in `UITableView` datasource `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, that prevents limit of array. Also set proper `return` count for `numberOfCells`.

Something like, if you've 4 values in your array. So there'll be 3 invisible cells should made.

`1st Cell`

`blank`

`2nd Cell`

`blank`

`3rd Cell`

`blank`

`4th Cell`

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
    return [xmlParser.calls count] + (([xmlParser.calls count]%2)+1);
}
```

In your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method,
do condition like,

```
if(indexPath.row==0) 
{ 
    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
} 
else if((indexPath.row+1)%2!=0) 
{ 
   cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; 
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"%d is blank cell",indexPath.row);
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSCFConstantString stringByAppendingString:]: nil argument'

Comment: and if I comment them out, I am still getting the same error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'

Comment: @JonErickson, First error comes due to you're trying to appending `nil` (blank) string into `NSString`, you should condition like `if (str.lenght==0) {str = @" "; }` and second error, I've explained it in answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are multiplying the array count, no big deal

```
return [xmlParser.calls count] * 2;
```

but you should then divide the `indexPath.row` by to 2 to get the real index of the datasource. The table assumes that you have a datasource with the size 2n, so the table will access 0 .. 2n using the indexpath.

```
JointCAD *currentCall = [[xmlParser calls] objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row/2)]
```

Comment: this is not going to work (you'we made a typo, `indexPath.row/2` but not `indexPath.row]/2`)